403 error when requesting AWS temporary credentials via iot
I'm following this guide to generate credentials for AWS services using a thingName, aws-iot cert and key:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/authorizing-direct-aws.html
I'm getting an opaque 403 error. The cert, key, and thingName allow an MQTT connection. How can I determine why the request is denied? Are there cloud watch errors recorded somewhere? If so, which log group might help me?
John

Did you really follow the guide? because you need to call the credential endpoint first using https. And you need the policy of your thing to have the assumeRoleWithCertificate. + you need to have a role in the role alias section....

In this case I'd forgotten to give the iot client the iot:AssumeRoleWithCertificate privilege.
If you're following procedure in the link, note that in step 3, the section called 'Configure the PassRole permissions' assigns role passing privileges to  an arbitrary user, that is not associated with the iot client. I skipped this step and successfully receive temporary credentials.
